# Unable to set a variable with an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a call to ajax which seems to execute properly, but I can't set a breakpoint in the success section of the call. The underlying database is changed and I want to return a value of the number of items that have been changed in 'tppunk'. In debugging with Firebug, the debugger doesn't stop in 'success' even though it does succeed. Instead, I jump to the code after the call and 'tppunk' is identified as undefined. Here's my code:

```
var json = {'tagset': tagset}
var tppunk;
$.ajax({
    url: clr_url_base+'savetags.php?data='+encodeURIComponent($.toJSON(json)),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (d) {
        tppunk = d;
        $('h2').removeClass("changed");
        $('h2').addClass("saved");
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('h2').removeClass("changed");
        $('h2').addClass("saved");
    }
});

if(corp == "CPA")
    window.opener.$('span.tppunk').text(tppunk);
```

Comment: There has been numerous questions similar to this on SO. Clue what you are doing is async and place some debug statements and see what happens and when.

Comment: These suggestions make sense and I will pursue them. This aynchronicity stuff is not intuitive, and I haven't understood the callback methodology. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX call is asynchronous, so your code hits

```
$.ajax ...
```

and sends a request to the server.

It then merrily continues on its way and hits

```
if(corp=="CPA") ...
```

At some later point in time, the server responds and your success function is called. This probably occurs well after your `if(corp` block.

What you'll want to do is put the `if(corp` block inside your success call somehow.